# Is there any way to Integrate Outlook Add-in and Azure Application Insights?

Tags: ms-office, azure-application-insights, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to create an Outlook Add-in which works on clicking the send button. It should try to check if the recipients are external users and display a custom dialog box with two buttons namely "Send Anyway" and "Don't send". Then, I want to calculate the metrics like how number of times the pop-up was displayed, how many number of times a button was clicked etc. and make these metrics available on Application Insights.

I tried using this in my outlook Add-in's JS code:

```
const appInsights = new ApplicationInsights({
    config: {
        instrumentationKey: '*****',
    },
});
appInsights.loadAppInsights();
appInsights.trackEvent({
                        name: 'PopupDisplayed',
                        properties: {
                            recipients: externalRecipients.join(';'),
                        },
                    });
```

This is taking long time to process and is finally giving me an alert saying that "My Add-in is not available now, so Try Later". It would be of great help!! if anyone could share me documentations and code references that can help me in displaying a custom dialog box Onsend and also integrating the popup with Application Insights, if this is achievable.